# Query to delete duplicate records from MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates

I have a table with multiple duplicate records. I'm using MS Access. I would like to delete duplicate records using a query. This is the table sample:

```
ID        | Holiday
----------+------------------
1234      | 1
1234      | 1
2345      | 2
2345      | 2
5678      | 5
```

I want my query result to be:

```
ID        | Holiday
----------+------------------
1234      | 1
2345      | 2
5678      | 5
```

Is here any way to do this in MS Access? Perhaps using SQL? I tried using query wizard but it only gives me list of duplicate records. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data does not include a primary key by which the data can be ordered, the easiest way to yield a unique data set would be to use a `select into` query to generate a new table, e.g.:

```
select distinct * into NewTable from YourTable
```

You can then optionally delete your original table using:

```
drop table YourTable
```